# Fastest way to convert a bytearray into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `bytearray` which I want to convert to a numpy array of `int16` to perform FFT operations on. The bytearray is coming out of a UDP socket so first I convert two consecutive bytes into an `int16` using `struct.unpack`, and then convert it a numpy array using `np.asarray`.

Current approach, however, is too slow. Original `bytearray` is of length 1e6 bytes, so each of the mentioned steps (`struct.unpack` and `np.asarray`) takes 20 ms and with a total of 40ms. This is a relatively long frame time for my applications so I need it a bit shortened.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
temp1 = self.data_buffer[0:FRAME_LEN_B]
self.temp_list = np.asarray(struct.unpack('h' * (len(temp1) // 2), temp1))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `int.from_bytes` rather than `struct.unpack`?

Comment: Forget my suggestion -- `timeit` shows that `int.from_bytes` is slower.

Comment: You might also want to pre-format your struct into a `Struct` object so you don't have to construct the string every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`np.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html). This can wrap any object supporting the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), which [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) explicitly does, into an array:

```
arr = np.frombuffer(self.data_buffer, dtype=np.int16, size=FRAME_LEN_B // 2)
```

You can manipulate the array however you want after that: slice, reshape, transpose, etc.

If your native byte order is opposite to what you have coming in from the network, you can swap the interpretation order without having to swap the data in-place:

```
dt = np.dtype(np.int16)
dt.newbyteorder('>')
arr = np.frombuffer(self.data_buffer, dtype=dt, size=FRAME_LEN_B // 2)
```

If the order is non-native, operations on the array may take longer, as the data will have to be swapped every time on the fly. You can therefore change the byte order in-place ahead of time if that is the case:

```
arr.byteswap(inplace=True)
```

This will overwrite the contents of the original packet. If you want to make a separate copy, just set `inplace=False`, which is the default.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually so much faster than my previous approach. I don't know why, but I have been getting inconsistent frame rates with this method; I'm not sure if it's because of  the `np.frombuffer` or some other part in my code. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @MiladMokhtari. This literally builds an array object on an existing buffer. No data should be copied, hence the speed. If you overwrite previous packets somehow, you will mess with the array as you're processing it